# Jupyter notebook loses directory tree periodically

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter

After a time of inactive (1-2 days) jupyter notebook display nothing in directory tree (http://localhost/tree).

How I can refresh directory tree without restart server? I don't want restart server because the data in memory. Notebooks works well by direct link to `*.ipynb` (http://localhost/tree/my_code/untitled.ipynb). Jupyter started on Windows Server 2012.

Answer (score 1):

It is a bug in the latest update to jupyter notebooks. The workaround is to downgrade back to the most recent working copy. I really wanted a way that used conda and not pip to downgrade, and I found an excellent solution. Anaconda keeps an archive of previous releases of the entire system (conda + jupyter + spyder + ...). You can find the archive here:

https://repo.continuum.io/archive/

For me, the version that worked was the July 2019 release

https://repo.continuum.io/archive/Anaconda3-2019.07-Windows-x86_64.exe

First you must uninstall Anaconda completely and then install the archived version.